# Add asset path in rails mountable engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

How can I add `vendor/assets/javascripts/mymountableengine` or `vendor/assets/stylesheets/mymountableengine` to my mountable engine's assets paths? I want to be able to require files from these folders in my mountable engine's application.js/application.css file with sprockets.

Rails 3.2.2

Thanks.

Comment: Afaik paths to engine's assets are added by default. [This answer] provides a bit more information on the topic. Have you tried requiring engine's assets in your app's manifest?

Comment: Your link is broken =). I do have access to assets in app/assets, but I added the vendor directory manually and want to include it in the paths. I haven't added the engine's assets in my app's manifest, I just load them with ```javascript_include_tag 'engine/application.js'``` - this works great and I get all the assets in ```app/assets```, however when I try to require files from ```vendor/assets``` in ```engine/application.js``` I get an error that the file does not exists.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5877665/357743).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm after, I need to require my files in ```engine/vendor/assets/``` in ```application.js/application.css```. if I put ```//= require fileinvendorassets``` I get an error that the file does not exist (since engine/vendor is not in the load path)

Answer (score 9):

Turns out they were already loaded! Just put them in the wrong directory: `engine/vendor/assets/javascripts/engine` - putting them in `engine/vendor/assets/javascripts` made them requireable. For others, just check `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` to see which paths are loaded, I believe engines use the parents Sprockets environment, so to add paths just use `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << "path/here"`

Comment: This was driving me crazy and running `rails console` then `puts Rails.application.config.assets.paths.join "\n"` helped me find that the default vendor folder was not being included for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I do like this:

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine

    config.assets.paths << File.expand_path("../../assets/stylesheets", __FILE__)
    config.assets.paths << File.expand_path("../../assets/javascripts", __FILE__)
    config.assets.precompile += %w( my_engine.css )

  end
end
```

Comment: Note: Be sure to use << and not += here. As of Rails 4.2 "+=", at least from my experience, will fail silently and break your app without throwing any errors.

Comment: Yes, we should add elements to array, not replace it, with with `precompile` is ok.