# How to make bootstrap & jquery working together in rails 3.2.12 app which has rail engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, jquery

We are working on a `rails 3.2.12` apps which has multiple `rails engines`. There are nav bar and user menu in `main app`. The functioning module is in rails `engine`. One of the `engine` is called `customerx` which enable user to manage customer info, such as creating customer, changing customer info and such.

Last week we added `bootstrap` in our rails_main app to take advantage of the nice format of bootstrap. The problem we find is that the jquery `datepicker` and html inserting features stop working in rails engines.

Here is the `main app's application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

There is require bootstrap in application.js.

We did not put require bootstrap in rails engine's application.js. Here is engine's application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

When clicking add_more_contact link on the `new customer form`, there is an error in `firebug`:

```
ReferenceError: add_fields is not defined
```

Also `datepicker` in all `engines` is not working any more after adding bootstrap in main app.

We did some search online. `bootstrap` requires `jquery` to work. However there may be conflict between `jquery-ui` and `bootstrap`. We follow the advice by putting the `require bootstrp` at the bottom of `main app's application.js`. Also we tried to use `$.noConflict()` in `main app's application.js`. However those are not enough to make `bootstrap` and `jquery` working together. What else we need to do to make `jquery(ui)` in `rails engine` working with `bootstrap`? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we found out was that the `assets` for `rails engines` were not loaded at all. That's why all js features did not work for engins. Here is the `main app's application.js` now:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
//= require my_engine_name/application.js
//= require bootstrap
```

Here is the post which provides the solution about how to load the assets for rails engine:

[Engine's assets with Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877619/engines-assets-with-rails-3-1)

Why adding bootstrap caused the disappearing of the engine assets, we don't know yet. Hopefully someone can shed the light on the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Fix add_fields

Firstly let's fix add_fields. This function called jQuery(`$(link)`) but defined in global namespace. That's why it won't work.

To write a function utilizing jQuery functions in global namespace, you need to write it as a jQuery plugin

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.add_fields = function(link, association, content) {
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
    $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Then you can use `add_fields()` within jQuery.

#### Bootstrap and jQuery UI

There is some conflict between these two libs. You can't use them together without any change.

Here are two solutions as I know, according to you situation:

1. Give up jQuery UI at all and use Bootstrap's datapicker. It is nice as well.
2. Use a tweaked lib containing them two, such as [jQuery UI Bootstrap](http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap), or [a matching Rails gem](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/jquery-ui-bootstrap-rails) for this lib.

I would prefer solution #1 if you want to stick with Bootstrap and there is not too much datepicker to revise.

Comment: Very interesting solution.A few questions. 1. add_fields is in engine's application.js & engine is in its isolated namespace. Could add_fields function in engine be its own namespace as well? 2. If we give up jquery-ui, what else functionality of jquery we are going to lose? there are autocomplete, manipulating html on the front and rails ajax calls in the engine now. 3. What we need to do if we decide to use bootstrap only and give up jquery-ui? Probably we need to remove the //=require jquery-ui in application.js and also the cdn link in application.html. Any example we can follow? Thanks.

Comment: We changed add_fields in one engine with the code above. somehow there still is no add_fields in application.js in main app when we checked the html source by clicking  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>. What could we have missed?

Comment: @user938363, 1. For giving up jquery UI, you won't lost too much, juqeryUI is just a UI lib, Bootstrap also has lots of UI as well, and you can always use other third party UI plugins for certain functionality such as autocomplete, generally they are better than jQueryUI because they focus. For functions like manipulating html and ajax, they are nothing to do with jQueryUI, they are parts of jQuery which you still have. Bootstrap depends on jQuery as well. 2. For add_fields, what you are talking in comment is about requiring, you need to check if the file is correctly required.

Comment: We did a test on about add_fields. What is missing the engine's application.js was not loaded (only main app's application.js loaded). If we create another .js file with the add_fields and datapicker in main app javascript folder, then those function worked.

Comment: @user938363, nice your code works :) I'm not quite familiar with engine yet, the code in answer is mainly about writing jQuery functions.